# Configuring SSL on Jetty

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, keystore, jetty-9

I'm trying to configure my jetty environment to be able to have a secure connection.

I've run the steps described on the official jetty documentation :https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.31.v20200723/jetty-ssl-distribution.html. but with no success..

Steps to recreate:

1. java -jar start.jar --create-startd --add-to-start=ssl
2. java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=ssl,conscrypt
3. java -jar start.jar --add-to-startd=ssl,https
4. update start.d/ssl.ini with the values:

```
--module=ssl
jetty.ssl.host=0.0.0.0
jetty.ssl.port=8583
jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath=etc/keystore
jetty.sslContext.trustStorePath=etc/keystore
jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword=OBF:
jetty.sslContext.keyManagerPassword=OBF:
jetty.sslContext.trustStorePassword=OBF:
 #Enable client certificate authentication.
jetty.sslContext.needClientAuth=true
```

For generating the keystore I followed the steps:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out jetty.key
openssl req -new -x509 -key jetty.key -out jetty.crt
keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias jetty -file jetty.crt -trustcacerts
openssl req -new -key jetty.key -out jetty.csr
openssl pkcs12 -inkey jetty.key -in jetty.crt -export -out jetty.pkcs12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore
```

As last step I've obfuscated the password and updated it into start.d/ssl.ini file.

## ISSUE

I'm facing with an error which say something like

```
2020-09-28 13:51:46.896:INFO::main: Logging initialized @523ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2020-09-28 13:51:47.387:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.  See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
2020-09-28 13:51:47.414:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.31.v20200723; built: 2020-07-23T17:57:36.812Z; git: 450ba27947e13e66baa8cd1ce7e85a4461cacc1d; jvm 11.0.8+10-LTS
2020-09-28 13:51:47.460:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///opt/jetty-distribution-9.4.31.v20200723/webapps/] at interval 1
2020-09-28 13:51:47.796:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509=X509@6853425f(jetty,h=[jettyhttp2sample.organicdesign.org],w=[]) for Server@5a9f4771[provider=Conscrypt,keyStore=file:///opt/jetty-distribution-9.4.31.v20200723/etc/keystore,trustStore=file:///opt/jetty-distribution-9.4.31.v20200723/etc/keystore]
2020-09-28 13:51:47.799:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: Unable to get KeyManagerFactory instance for algorithm [SunX509] on provider [Conscrypt], using default
2020-09-28 13:51:47.882:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@46c1a1fc{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{localhost:8443}
2020-09-28 13:51:47.886:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@7b205dbd{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-09-28 13:51:47.887:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1514ms
```

**Unable to get KeyManagerFactory instance for algorithm [SunX509] on provider [Conscrypt], using default**

Any help is appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using this version of Jetty: jetty-distribution-9.4.31.v20200723 and running in a ubuntu.20.04 distribution

Answer (score 1):

There's no error being reported here, this is normal fallback operations for alternate providers (conscrypt in your case).

The Conscrypt security provider doesn't support the `SunX509` algorithm for `KeyManagerFactory`, so it falls back to the JVM default implementation.

*Also, don't edit files in your jetty-home / jetty-distribution directly, that's a much bigger WARN, use the distribution correctly and separate your jetty-home from your jetty-base per the documentation linked in that WARN message.  This ancient technique for managing the configuration of Jetty standalone has been completely removed in Jetty 10 and Jetty 11!*